# Instantiate abstract class using class of variable

Tags: java, abstract

For obvious reasons, we cannot instantiate an abstract class directly like so:

```
AbstractObj obj = new AbstractObj();
```

Where AbstractObj is a class of the form:

```
public abstract class AbstractObj {
//... Body omitted 
}
```

However if we have extending classes, such as the following:

```
public class ConcreteObj extends AbstractObj {
//... Body omitted
}

public class AnotherObj extends AbstractObj {
//... Body omitted
}
```

Is it possible to instantiate an object in the following manner? This determines which constructor has to be used based on the class of the variable passed in. Assume for now that o1 and o2 are guaranteed to be of the same type.

```
protected AbstractObj computeDiff(AbstractObj o1, AbstractObj o2){
    AbstractObj delta = ...?
}
```

For example, in the above, if o1 is of type ConcreteObj, is there a way to recognise at runtime whether or not it is of this type and use the appropriate constructor?

Comment: you want to call a constructor after constructing the object?

Comment: You can do it with : `o1.getClass()`. Then, if it has a default constructor, you can call it with `o1.getClass().newInstance()`.

Comment: Abstract classes can not be instantiated but you can instantiate its concretions.

Comment: You can use `instanceof` to check whether `o1` is indeed a `ConcreteObj`.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle That works, if you want to add that as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: I think you approach is incorrect. I would create a method for computing diff inside the object, not in a third class

Comment: @RealSkeptic If AbstractObj has numerous fields that can be checked, including these fields in the overridden subclass specific method would be unnecessary repetition.

Comment: This kind of problem you're facing is usually a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: You will then put the checking of the common fields in a (protected) method in the superclass and call it from the subclasses.

Comment: @adickinson There are ways to implement this without involving code repetition and reflective instantiation. You're copping out and choosing to write crappy code.

Comment: Implement AbstractObj.clone() and instead of external diff implement AbstractObj.removeAll(AbstractObj). Your diff becomes o1.clone().removeAll(o2). When you override those methods in the subclasses and call superclasses diligently, you don't need to repeat any code or worry about type compatibility. Also, don't call it "diff" unless you have means to describe fields that were present only in the "left hand side" parameter and which were only in RHS.

Comment: @Torben Not `clone()`. That is a code smell in its own right.

Comment: About 100% of the times people call clone a code smell is because they do not understand how it works and try to force it into a hole it doesn't fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here :

```
protected AbstractObj computeDiff(AbstractObj o1, AbstractObj o2){
   AbstractObj delta = ...?
}
```

You can get the concrete class of `o1` with `o1.getClass()`. Then, if this concrete class has a default constructor, you can call it with `Class.newInstance()` :

```
protected AbstractObj computeDiff(AbstractObj o1, AbstractObj o2) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException{
   AbstractObj delta = o1.getClass().newInstance();
}
```

Comment: This will work, but it does require that all subclasses of `AbstractObj` have a no-args constructor.

Comment: @Jesper Yes, it is often a requirement for classes dealing with reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use instanceof statement. You can cast o1 to ConcreteObj and use this class' methods or fields.

```
if(o1 instanceof ConcreteObj){
  //((ConcreteObj)o1).someMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is definitely code smell. Do not use instanceof. Do not use reflection.**

Absolutely do not continue on this path.

All your `AbstractObj` instances implement a common set of operations. Since your `computeDiff` operates on AbstractObjs, it must not depend on any special features of the different implmentations it receives.

Therefore it does not matter what type of an object the method receives or returns, as long as they all adhere to the AbstractObj definition. You can return an anonymous class that extends AbstractObj if you want or any other subclass. You can even create a specific subclass for just this purpose. But whatever you return, it must not return anything more than AbstractObj.

Declaring the parameters and the return value as `AbstractObj` is a contract you sign with whoever calls your method. Don't break your contracts.